# How to change font in BigQuery data [Data Cleaning]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In a Bigquery table I have the same value but with 2 different type of fonts (ℂ and Cartagena), for a data cleaning process how can I put it all in one type of font, since it filters as 2 different values?

[Example of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMNY9.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NORMALIZE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#normalize) function as in below example

```
with your_table as (
  select 'ℂ' col union all
  select 'Cartagena'
)
select *, normalize(col, NFKC) normalized_col
from your_table
```

with output

[image]